# Creating authorization token for google cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am writing an application to fetch query logs from google cloud sql using stack driver monitoring. I am able to retrieve the logs using API explorer. I will be using a curl call to download the logs.

> curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" --header
>   'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'x-referer:
>   https://developers.google.com' -X POST --data
>   '{"resourceNames":["projectname"],"filter":"logName=logname"}'
>   "https://content-logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?fields=entries(jsonPayload%2ClogName%2Coperation%2CreceiveTimestamp%2CtextPayload%2Ctimestamp)&key=APIkey"

API key is available in the interface. I have downloaded the json with client details. But I am not able to find any documentation on how to generate ACCESS_TOKEN in this case. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default  
print-access-token) ...
```

or set:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
```

and then:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" ...
```

Comment: should I install gcloud(Cloud SDK) in my machine to run this command?

Comment: Is there any other way to get ACCESS_TOKEN? I do not want to install any other tool on my machine.

Comment: It is possible to generate ACCESS_TOKEN using JWT. I am trying with that now.

Comment: You can use service account authorization without OAuth: developers.google.com/identity/protocols/…, but have to call logging.googleapis.com (instead of content-logging.googleapis.com). It is a supported API: github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google